# How to solve 'invalid object name' in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

This is the error message returned:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid object name 'ENG_PREP'.

It happens after I try the following query:

```
insert into ENG_PREP VALUES('572012-01-1,572012-01-2,572012-01-3,572013-01-1,572013-01-2',
'',
'500',
'',
'A320 P.001-A',
'Removal of the LH Wing Safety Rope',
'',
'',
'',
'0',
'',
'AF',
'12-00-00-081-001',
'',
'',
'',
'',
'',
'',
'' )
```

Comment: Well, it just means that in whatever database you're running your query, there is no "ENG_PREP" table. Were you running this in Management Studio and maybe accidentally left it on [master]? put a `USE [YourDatabaseName]` at the top of that and see what happens.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't necessarily mean that it can't find "ENG_PREP" in your SQL insert query itself.  Check any triggers that run on that table as well and make sure all of them have the exact table name spelled correctly.

This JUST happened to me when debugging a stored procedure and it took me half an hour to find it.

Answer (score 10):

It means that it doesn't know what `ENG_PREP` is.

You need to use a `'use xxx'` (where xxx is the database name where the `ENG_PREP` lives) command first to tell it what database you are using. And once you do that, you need to make sure that `ENG_PREP` is present in that database.

If you're using .Net to connect, you need to make sure you specify the initial catalog so it knows what database to use, here's an example excerpt from a `web.config`:

```
<add name="SqlConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=your_db_name_here;Integrated Security=True"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 4):

I means the table ENG_PREP doesn't exist in the connection you are using.

Check if you are connected to the right server/database. Also check the table name.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like it can't find the table.

Check that you're connected to the correct database.
That the table exists and that it's the correct spelling.

Answer (score 1):

I too faced this error in plain text query.. In my web application, i have used three connection string.. i had specified that query with particular DB Name and Table name.. My error get solved.. Hope it may useful for someone..

Answer (score 1):

Currently learning SQL server machine learning service and I had the same issue where database table pulls from one level below but the FROM where the location was different than finding a current location.

So I wrote exactly FROM where data was coming:

```
FROM [WideWorldImporters].[Application].[Cities_Archive]
```

Hope this could help at initial level