# SQL maintenance job failing: "Invalid object name 'Confluence.sys.Partitions'. Changed database context to 'master'

Tags: sql-server, maintenance-plan, invalid-object-name

My database is called "Confluence". The maintenance job has always failed since that job was setup 6 months ago. Attempting to run the job manually also fails with same error.

```
Executed as user: NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility Version 11.0.2100.60 for 64-bit Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Started: 1:00:00 AM Progress: 2020-05-12 01:00:05.53
Source: {AB5561C0-62BD-4185-A869-1AD993B98428}
Executing query "DECLARE @Guid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
EXECUTE msdb..sp...".: 100% complete End Progress
Error: 2020-05-12 01:02:57.66 Code: 0xC002F210
Source: Execute T-SQL Statement Task Execute SQL Task
Description: Executing the query "use master; exec ap_RebuildIndexes 30, 80, 'Confl..." failed with the following error: "Invalid object name 'Confluence.sys.Partitions'. Changed database context to 'master'. ".
Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly. End Error Warning: 2020-05-12 01:02:57.66 Code: 0x80019002 Source: Subplan_1 Description: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED. The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (1) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors. End Warning DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1). Started: 1:00:00 AM Finished: 1:02:58 AM Elapsed: 177.607 seconds. The package execution failed. The step failed.
```

The attached screenshot shows the actual maintenance job (which an index rebuild followed by an update statistics of db called "Confluence").

[image: maintenance job design]

Are you able to assist please?

The SQL Server instance is SQL 2012 (SP1).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve 'invalid object name' in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069356/how-to-solve-invalid-object-name-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

My hints:

- Confluence database does not exists on this server anymore or it was renamed
- Default collation of the database has changed to a case sensitive
- Check or debug that stored procedure or send us its CREATE PROC script (sp_RebuildIndexes)